# KDE themes used to style Qt4 application

Tags: qt, qt4, themes, kde-plasma, multiplatform

can kde themes be used to style multi platform (linux/windows) Qt4 applications ?

Comment: I'm looking for a step-by-step howto :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about Qt Styles([QStyle](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstyle.html)) that are used in traditional C++ KDE themes(non Plasma or ini themes) then yes you can do that to some extent, though you may have to adjust/fix some(or more) things since their mostly written with the KDE theme purpose in mind. One good example would be to fix or ensure the cross-platform compatibility(the theme might use additional platform specific libraries). Then there's also the licensing issue that you definitely have to take into consideration, since most of those themes are under GNU GPL.

If you're talking about [Qt Stylesheets](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/stylesheet.html), you are out of luck, since currently KDE doesn't support any way of theming using Qt Stylesheets, thus you have no KDE Stylesheet themes to **use**.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you build/copy all dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Qt uses every platform's native API to render the widgets, hence platform specific themes cannot be applied on other platforms.

Since themes maybe third-party, it becomes more difficult.

Comment: This is incorrect, Qt doesn't use native APIs to render widgets like wxWidgets does, instead Qt interrogates the native looks whenever possible like uxtheme.dll on Windows and then it tries to emulate that look as best as possible. Thus in an essence Qt still paints the widgets itself, but it does it smart and really well nowadays without breaking the flexibility that own painting allows for(Qt Stylesheets or QStyle), which it would if using native widgets apis. Take a look here for hard proof: http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/gui/styles/qwindowsxpstyle.cpp#line342